# Captive portal with chillispot without DNS

Tags: internal-dns, openwrt, captive-portal

I'm trying to set up a captive portal in openWRT using chillispot. 
My goal is to have an open network and display a static html with information without internet connection at all and without any login. 
I've got it working at home, when the WRT router is connected to the internet. But I need to use the solution without connection to the internet. I'm not sure if this is possible, because without internet there is no DNS resolution, and chillispot does not work without DNS.

Maybe there is an option to do something using IPtables or something similar to force all traffic in the network to go to a single IP?